# Node Wrangler: revert preview node to previous flow

Tags: node-editor, add-on

Haven't found an answer by search: is there a shortcut to revert the Shift + Ctrl + LMB shortcut in Node Wrangler that will return the flow setup of the node tree to what it was before previewing a node?

It adds time on either side of inspecting and adjusting a node to render, zoom and move out of part of the tree, and reconnect the disconnected node, render and then zoom and move back for comparisons with the full material.

Or am I blissfully missing something equally useful, like an alternate viewing node? I am primarily using shader and geometry nodes.

Thanks!

Edit:

If anyone else is frustrated with this: one workaround I sometimes use is to make a tiny workspace window that focuses wholly on the last node that would complete the material so that I can quickly mouse over and CTRL + Shift + LMB it back into action. This requires real estate, though.

Comment: Just the normal Ctrl-Z (Undo)?

Comment: Thanks, I'm adjusting, though. So undo would undo all changes that I'd have to redo after undoing all steps to that point, which is 100% more repeated steps than a manual reroute. CTRL-Z has inconsistent behaviour with node adjustments: doesn't always return settings, replace accidentally deleted nodes... (color ramps occasionally do not undo flag adjustments, for one example). In virtually all cases it is more wasteful to hold all these values in my head/spare save/revert file than to just replug a noodle. I'd like a reconnect shortcut to avoid laggy tree navigation while VP re-renders.

Comment: @sevens Maybe you will like it: https://youtu.be/1ZiEaqsAvJU

Comment: Yes. If you've done anything else in the meantime Ctrl-Z will of course undo it. I was just thinking you wanted to toggle immediately between connect and disconect.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for your help. & Thank you, @ugorek, but I'm currently having a lot of issues with node trees being laggy (haven't quite sorted out what's wrong--if not just too big of a tree--but sliders often have a 2 second delay, making fine tuning a frustrating time drain) and I think that add-on may only make the lag more intense or frustrating. It might have some use when I've got this issue sorted though, thanks.